# Error retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, trial

I'm implementing an app with in app billing(subscription)with my own product ids and the purchase works fine till I change the trail duration on the Google Develper Console from 0 to 7(or more).I'm testing on a device.

I'm getting the Error: Error retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01].

Also there are two other errors with may interact with it:(Logcat)

05-12 00:17:14.770: E/Volley(28168): [2645] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase

05-12 00:20:10.820: E/Finsky(28940): [2769] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsztzcft61Os148JZc27iUsw' failed!

Pls help!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play error "Error while retrieving information from server \[DF-DFERH-01\]"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01)