# Google Play Store: users cant download app because of error df-dferh-01

Tags: android, download, console, google-play

I'm getting a lot of emails from users that can't download my app in the Google Play Store. They all get "Error while retrieving information from server [df-dferh-01]".

I know that there are sometimes local issues with some devices that cause this but the users can download other apps, just not mine.

EDIT: This is not solvable by the downloader at all... This is an app wide problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please search your title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play error "Error while retrieving information from server \[DF-DFERH-01\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01)

Comment: As the question title says: this is not something the downloader can fix! This has to be fixed by the developer...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! There was a warning in the Google Developer Console...

My app uses some permissions that require an privacy policy. I failed to update my store page. This denied the download of the app!

--> Just provide a privacy policy!

Comment: I am getting this error for internal test release. I do have a privacy policy page. But all the people (testers) I sent it to, getting this error. It's weird that this error dates back to 2012(AFAIK). and still, we don't have a solid solution.