# Error DF-DFERH-01 when update the app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I had uploaded an app on Google Play, it used to be available. But after updating, error `DF-DFERH-01` occurs for many users of my app. I [cleared cache of Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01), and [also set a privacy policy in the settings of the application page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265360/google-play-store-users-cant-download-app-because-of-error-df-dferh-01), which didn't help.

How can this problem be solved?

P.S. Other apps are updated without errors.

P.P.S. This problem is for all users who use my app

Comment: You are probably best contacting Google Play support. This can be done via the help icon (a "?" question mark) in the Play Console. It is an internal error for your app.

Answer (score 0):

To Eliminate the DF-DFERH-01 issue of Play Store, I clicked Reset App Preferences (settings > apps > ⋮ > reset app Preferences). It worked.

Actually, the issue of DF-DFERH-01 doesn’t start when updating the Play Store app(s), it starts when you mistakenly force stopped app.

Answer (score 0):

I see this when I try to downgrade a subscription and I'm using ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE.

Comment: I know this is late, but I also see the error when upgrading with that proration mode. I raised this issue with google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/176380832.

(Generally it's recommended to use ProrationMode.DEFERRED for downgrades, but they have their own problems, which I also raised: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/176381211.)