# Getting Error Retrieving Apps from server [DF-DFERH-01]

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to install my organizational free apps on Tablet. Getting the below error. It was working before but recently I got this issue.I have tried to reset my device but again the same issue.

[image]

I know this is a bug from Google server end. But need some help.
What I have tried

- Reset / Factory Reset my Device.
- Select Google Play Store and select uninstall updates.
- Select Google Play Store and cleared cache, cleared data and did force stop. but no luck.
- Tried with another email address.
- Remove the account, added a new account did sync, but no luck.
- Checked the Google [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36952161), no updates available.
- Tried [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RyanLestage/posts/RbGpuAsjhoN) solution but no luck.
- Tried with [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01), but no luck.

  Any help or idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I am getting the same problem when trying to access the music tab.

Comment: @skydev No, I don't know the exact solution. However, I tried with google gsuite account it works for me.

Comment: ok thanks. I think I'll just have to wait for android 9 to release in my country and then try @Janmejoy

Comment: @skydev cool :)